# Functional testing a daemon in Python

Tags: python, daemon, functional-testing

First, when I say daemon, I don't necessarily mean an application that's been spawned as such, but merely one that is intended to be run that way; in this case, an HTTP load balancing component.

The crux of the issue is that, when you're doing functional testing on something like a Flask app, you can initialize the app and test it in the same process. When you're testing a networking daemon as in my case, it needs to be running in a separate process. So, my question is, are there any established tools or methods for doing this? My intuitive approach would be to spawn the process during the test setup, run tests against it by making requests with something like httplib2, and then kill it during teardown. This feels somewhat brittle, though, and I'm wondering if there are more elegant approaches.